# On iPhone and iPad, how do I get the latitude and longitude number from the Maps app or Google Maps app?

Tags: maps, google-maps

For example, on a desktop computer, if I enter in Google Maps website:

```
Golden Gate Park, San Francisco, CA
```

I can easily get in the URL

```
37.769425,-122.48840
```

If I use the Maps app or Google Maps app, is there a way to get the latitude and longitude number easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Apple Maps:

1. Open Maps for iOS.
2. Touch and hold an area of the map.
3. Pull up the "Marked Location" drawer. There is a section with latitude and longitude.

[For Google Maps:](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/18539?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1)

> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Google Maps app Google Maps.
> 2. Touch and hold an area of the map that isn’t labeled. You'll see a red pin appear.
> 3. At the bottom, tap Dropped pin. You'll now see the coordinates.

Comment: hm... they both worked... I just hope it is more intuitive, such as, if you are viewing a map, then if you tap the info icon or drag the info panel up, then it will tell you the attitude and longitude of the center of the map, or let you copy a link such as https://www.google.com/maps/@37.7694,-122.4905,17z